# How to get translation and rotation from glMultMatrixf?

Tags: opengl

I am looking at old OpenGL code like [this](https://github.com/raulmur/ORB_SLAM2/blob/master/src/MapDrawer.cc):

```
 glPushMatrix();
    glMultMatrixf(Twc.m);

    glLineWidth(mCameraLineWidth);
    glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex3f(0,0,0);
    //... more glVertex3f
    glEnd();

glPopMatrix();
```

It creates a cone like object using this glMultMatrixf api. Say we want to modernize it using something like `add(const Eigen::Vector3f &   translation, const Eigen::Quaternionf &     rotation)`. How to get translation and rotation from `glMultMatrixf`?

Comment: glMultMatrixf in the old API just applies the transformation (any combination of translation, rotation, scale) to subsequent geometry. Your createAt is presumably just a translation. Find the code that creates the Twc.m matrix and see what values it uses

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get back anything from the result of `glMultMatrix` - you already have the matrix `Twc.m` which contains the composed transformations for this object - so actually, the use of `Twc.m` as separate matrix is the only part of this code which would stay the same, when switching to modern OpenGL. You'd just apply that matrix in the vertex shader (in conjunction with view and projection transformations) nowadays.